# Какие числа приводятся к true

Tags: javascript

`true` - это же все числа кроме `0`, да?

Comment: Все не проверял, а Чак зажал ответ, но да, попробуйте сами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В JavaScript любое значение может быть неявно преобразовано в булево. В **false** преобразуются следующие значения: *undefined*, *null*, *0*, *-0*, *NaN* и *""* (пустая строка). Все другие значения, включая все объекты и массивы, неявно преобразуются а **true**. Всякий раз, когда интерпретатор JavaScript ожидает булево значение, он преобразует полученное значение любого типа в *false* или *true* согласно описанному выше правилу.

Answer (score 6):

Если обратиться к спецификации, за приведение в `boolean` отвечает абстрактная операция [`ToBoolean(argument)`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-toboolean)

Данная операция приводит аргумент к булевскому типу в соответствии с [таблицей](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#table-10)

Для типа `Number` в этой таблице указано следующее:

> Если  argument: `+0`, `-0`, или `NaN`, вернуть `false`, иначе – `true`.

---

Таким образом к `true` приводятся все числа кроме нолей и `NaN`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79471/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy-----true).